Disk 100% full, booting problems, after running PhotoRec
I'm an Ubuntu novice, Lost a drive with stored media, not my operating system drive. It just stopped showing up in Ubuntu, figured probably just died.  So used PhotoRec utility to try to recover data and was distracted with other home stuff plus didn't really fully know what I was doing anyway, started it recovering files onto my root drive instead of a different drive and filled it totally up by mistake. I couldn't even boot Ubuntu, it sucked up every byte.
I booted with a live disk USB and found the contents and deleted. I figured that would fix it, but ran Boot-Repair tool and it was still saying no free space and warning me that I'll still have a hard time booting. Even though I seemingly freed up like over a 100GB with deleting PhotoRec recovered files. Sure enough, I still couldn't boot and the drive lists 100% full.
Booting error hangs here listing the drive that is 100% full:
/dev/sda8: recovering journal
/dev/sda8: clean, 564532/7421952 files, 28967699/29669120 blocks

It also gives timeout errors waiting for other drives and says dependency failed. I assume it's trying to boot to other drives and timing out.
I got frustrated and just reinstalled Ubuntu. From the new Ubuntu I can access the old operating system partition, but I can't free up disk space. From the terminal that partition lists 100% full no matter what I try to delete. The stuff absolutely will not die, it's like a terminator. I wanna be able to get in there and wreck everything and destroy and delete with no permissions restrictions just because that partition is pissing me off at this point. If it shows 99% full instead of 100% I would take that as a win. Is it maybe going to trash somewhere? Some utilities do show space available, some show 100% full.
I would love to be able to resurrect my old Ubuntu partition and boot into it.
Below is the original partition that is reported as 100% full.
 /dev/sda8  739418112 976771071 237352960 113.2G Linux filesystem

edited to contain contents of sudo fdisk -l below. Also I don't have any vital data on this install, but would like to keep all the settings and everything if possible.
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 74.24 MiB, 77844480 bytes, 152040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 269.63 MiB, 282722304 bytes, 552192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 10.72 MiB, 11239424 bytes, 21952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 505.09 MiB, 529625088 bytes, 1034424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 10.32 MiB, 10821632 bytes, 21136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 38.73 MiB, 40615936 bytes, 79328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC  WDS500G2B0A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 49CC5EF2-7A8E-4EB9-B4B1-636277AD4024

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048  16386047  16384000   7.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda2   16386048  67586047  51200000  24.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   67586048 214636543 147050496  70.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  303106048 304027647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  304027648 304232447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda6  304232448 304265215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda7  304265216 739417389 435152174 207.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  739418112 976771071 237352960 113.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  214636544 303106047  88469504  42.2G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/sdb: 10.91 TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
Disk model: ST12000NM001G-2M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1305729D-0216-49FF-A8C5-551B5A5A524E

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 23437768703 23437766656 10.9T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdc: 10.91 TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
Disk model: ST12000NM001G-2M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FF2F116F-BDCE-4069-B111-0B8E83275E22

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 23437768703 23437766656 10.9T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/loop8: 476 KiB, 487424 bytes, 952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop9: 137.29 MiB, 143962112 bytes, 281176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop10: 66.17 MiB, 69382144 bytes, 135512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop11: 3.04 MiB, 3186688 bytes, 6224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop12: 211.49 MiB, 221761536 bytes, 433128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop13: 402.36 MiB, 421908480 bytes, 824040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop14: 55.66 MiB, 58363904 bytes, 113992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop15: 87.59 MiB, 91840512 bytes, 179376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop16: 38.83 MiB, 40714240 bytes, 79520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop17: 74.24 MiB, 77848576 bytes, 152048 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop18: 149.63 MiB, 156901376 bytes, 306448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop19: 10.54 MiB, 11051008 bytes, 21584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Please edit your question and put the output of:** sudo fdisk -l**, also clarify if you don't mind losing all data and reinstalling.

The most practical thing would be to delete the partitions /dev/sda1,2,3,8 and 9 from a live session using gparted, if you want to keep Windows and install Ubuntu on new partitions.

Thanks. So not possible to fix previous install? I  can mount the partition and use disk analyzer to figure out what is taking up space. I've deleted many files with nautilus but still the terminal drive listing says 100% full. Also, even though the files disappear after deletion, disk analyzer lists no change in % like the files are still there. I guess I can just wipe everything except windows with GParted like you say and reinstall again.

Indeed, it seems to me the most practical thing to do is to delete those partitions and install cleanly on three partitions, one for /, one for /home and one for swap.
